# How to get do a join in angularfire2 database for multiple Data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services

I've this Firebase Model :[Firebase model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTriW.png)

I need to get, for each "order" the: event detail ( red square ) and for each dancer the Dancer data ( green square )

For Red square I've implement this code and works nice :

```
// Collego la Lista da Firebase all'oggetto Lista Ordini
this.ListaOrdini = this.db.list('iscrizioni/' + this.statoUtente.UId) ;

// creo Oggetto con dati Evento
this.ListaOrdiniedEventi = this.ListaOrdini

  // Per ogni Ordine eseguo una SwitchMap 

  .switchMap(Ordini => {

    // Puntando all'evento tramite la chiave :

    let Evento = Ordini.map(Ordine => this.db
      .object(`Eventi/${Ordine.IDEvento}`)
    );

    // Se l'oggetto esiste combino i dati e li restituisco 

    return Evento.length === 0 ?
      Observable.of(Ordini) :
      Observable.combineLatest(...Evento, (...eventi) => {
        Ordini.forEach((Ordini, index) => {
          Ordini.DatiEvento = eventi[index] ;
        });
        return Ordini;
      });
  });
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to implement it for make it works also for dancer ( Green square )...

someone have any idea?